# Why admin grant is required if my app is only requesting User.Read permission?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

As you see my new registered app registration it's an app that only requires users to login.
Anything beyond the minimal requirements to work. I don't configured it to request any special sort of permission

[image]

When i Try lo login this message appears
*"Application needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it"*

**Why? The permissions the app is requesting are just basic ones . I don't understand why an admin consent is required.**

Many thanks

Comment: Whenever your users attempt to login it needs to issue a token for them that's why it requires to check permission each time to make sure that it has required permission along with admin consent. Hope you understand.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron yeah, but my question it's why, If i am not requesting for admin-consent privielges, it forces to it when I am logging in. I want the users to log in without the requirement of an admin providing consent

Comment: This permission won't ask you for admin consent. You need to check your code if it is requesting other resources or permissions.

Comment: It will ask for a user consent for the first time.

Comment: I downloaded the sample code from Azure portal, so it is not requesting anything special. @TonyJu

Comment: @X.Otano Did you refer to any document? I will check that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Most possible reasons for any administrator consented issue,*

1. App-only permissions always require a tenant [administrator’s consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#admin-consent). If your application requests an app-only permission and a user tries to sign in to the application, an error message is displayed saying the user isn’t able to consent.
2. Certain delegated permissions also require a tenant administrator’s consent. For example, the ability to write back to Azure AD as the signed in user requires a tenant administrator’s consent.

*Possible Solutions,*

1. The ***prompt=admin_consent*** parameter(which request permissions from admin) can be used as a parameter in the OAuth2/OpenID Connect authorization request to grant the admin consent .
2. Enable the [admin consent workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-admin-consent-workflow#enable-the-admin-consent-workflow)  , which gives end users a way to request access to applications that require admin consent.
3. Refer the permissions documentation for the [Microsoft Graph API indicate which permissions](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference) require admin consent.

Please refer [admin consent endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible reasons why users can't consent to *User.Read*:

1. User consent is disabled or restricted. Each customer can choose to disable or limit user consent to applications. In a tenant where user consent is disabled, for example, users can't consent to *any* permission.

   **Azure AD** > **Enterprise apps** > **User settings** > **Users can consent to apps...**
2. The app requires assignment. When an application is configured to require assignment for users to be able to sign in, users are not allowed to consent to that application.

   **Azure AD** > **Enterprise apps** > (select app) > **Properties** > **User assignment required?**